# Magento 2 : Load Roboto font in custom email template

Tags: magento2, email, transactional-mail

I want to load Roboto font in the custom email template.If load fonts from admin transactional email styles it displays properly in preview but can not load in an email.

Import code : @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

Please help me if anyone knows the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: No didn't resolve.Please answer this question if you have a solution

Comment: Did you declare that font in _email-extend.less? I'm not sure but email template on Magento2 assume to not support import font feature based on my experience .

Comment: Did you find any solution, guys?

Answer (score 0):

> /public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less

Contains @font-face declarations for custom fonts. This file is imported by the `_email-extend.less` file using an `@import` rule.